# mysql clustering

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

i am very new to mysql clustering.Can anybody explain me how to take backup on mysql clustering and how restore mysql clustering backup

Answer (score 0):

You can make a backup with the management node there is a command line to do this.

But before you should read the offizial mysql documentation for this.

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-cluster.html)

There you can find how to install / backup and many more.

Comment: Can you please share few of the commands

Comment: can you please share few commands and normal services which mysql cluster uses and how to find that

Comment: look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-cluster-backup-using-management-client.html) @rejesh.

Comment: Do you have some more questions? @rejesh